# Public transport or bus routes in Bali (Indonesia) beaches

Tags: public-transport, indian-citizens, buses, indonesia, bali

we are 2 Indian girls going to Bali (Indonesia) for 10 days. We would like to ask is there any good bus network from Denpasar to nearby beaches.We are unable to find good connections, If no bus service then is there any alternative or cheap taxi service in Bali?

Comment: Oh so amazing, I don't drive scooter but my friend does. Thanks both of you, very informative :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently visited Bali 2 months ago and I was also looking for the same information. Unfortunately there are only few bus routes  available and for visiting famous places like beaches and temples , there are not many options available to use public transport in Bali.  Still there are few options available to use transport in Bali Indonesia as a solo traveler.

- [**Kura-Kura Bus**](http://kura2bus.com/page/bus_lines), Although
  there are very few places in Bali which can be reached by buses and this bus service runs
  frequently to the limited stops regularly.
- **Rent a Scooter**: the most cheapest and feasible mode of
  transportation for solo or 2 traveler in Bali is renting a scooter.
  Personally I rented a motorbike for 5 days and I really found it
  really cheaper. Normally it cost somewhere between 4 to 5 USD per day
  depends for how long you need to rent a bike. Although there are
  plenty of scooter shops there, my hostel arranged 1 for me for 5 days
  and I paid around 22 USD along with the provided helmet. As I was staying in            Kuta, I visited Nusa Dua, Pandawa, Melasti, Blue point and Uluwatu temple on my rented motorbike and I found it a lot cheaper than using shuttle and taxi.

  Details regadring how to rent and what documents needed are available in this [website](http://www.brendansadventures.com/how-to-rent-a-scooter-in-bali/)
- [**GO-JEK**](https://www.go-jek.com/), this is another very
  interesting application which provides really cheap Ojek and Taxi in
  most places in Indonesia. I just came to know about this from my
  couchsurfing host in Malang who also downloaded the English version
  on my mobile. Personally I used it 3 times and always found really
  cheaper than local Ojek and taxi

  At Mengwi bus terminal there was only taxi driver available and was
  asking 20 USD to go to Kuta which was a bit expensive  considering
  Indonesia. However I also met a couple at Mengwi terminal and all of
  us arranged a shared taxi form GOJEK to Kuta and Denpasar which was really
  cheaper than regular taxi drivers.

  Also when I was going to Bali airport from kuta which is
  literally 5 Km, the regular Ojek was asking around 4 to 5 USD.
  However I called a Ojek from that application and it was just around
  1 USD to airport.

So basically there are many options available going to Bali beaches, sometimes your hotel/hostel can also arrange a shuttle buses for the desired places. I doubt there are many good buses network going to famous beaches.

Comment: Hi There, 
do you possibly know if there is a limitation of renting a scooter? I'm only 21 years old and only got a license for a car. My license is from Germany. Here  I'm only allowed to drive my 50ccm scooter. Is there a similar regulation in Bali?

Comment: @NiklasFett actually laws in Indonesia and in Bali are not that strict. when i rented a scooter I didn't even provide my licence copy. If you  have international motorbike licence that will be enough as you are already 21. Police always looking for Australian and European to stop get some bribe on the road so it is better to have international motorbike licence.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I accually don't own a International Motorbike License, since the laws here in germany are really strict and dont allow Motorbike licenses until one is 24. I can only drive up to 50 ccm. But oh well, i'll see what kind of scooter I'll get. :)

Comment: @NiklasFett also there is a chat from a user that you can get a tourist bike licence from denpasar police station https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294226-i7220-k6315082-Process_of_renting_a_scooter_motorbike-Bali.html

Answer (score 3):

I recently went to Bali three months ago. I hereby some tips for you. There are some vans at the aiport so you can bargain to make a good deal for about 10 usd/an hour but he only counted the time we travel on the road, not include the time he waited for us. He knows the shorcut and some affordable restaurant. Besides you can rent motobike in some place around Kuta beach. It suits for pockets, about 5usd. But I think the traffic is too bad, traffic jam happens from 10am to 11pm. It is not good way to ride if you are in Bali for the first time, you are easily stuck on the road because google map only shows the main road.

Comment: I agree with you traffic and google map not that good in Bali, Also nice pic at uluwatu temple :)